# How to fix the error in Tensorflow in installation in windows?

Tags: windows, tensorflow, keras, pip, anaconda

I installed tensorflow in Windows Powershell using

```
pip install tensorflow
```

But when import dependencies for keras(ResNet50) in anaconda jupyter notebook

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
import numpy as np
```

it gives me error as

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-22a529d637ab> in <module>
----> 1 from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
      2 from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
      3 from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
      4 import numpy as np

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

Comment: in jupyter run `!pip install tensorflow`

Comment: Probably because you have multiple Python installations and you installed the package in the wrong one.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Tensorflow not installed on Jupyter notebook
Follow the below instructions to install Tensorflow by creating virtual environment.

```
1. Set Up Anaconda Environments
conda create --name tf_env python=3

2. Activate the new Environment
source activate tf_env

3. Install tensorflow
pip install tensorflow

4. Launch jupyter notebook
jupyter notebook

5. Verify Tensorflow installation
import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__
```